I want to build androidx's appcompat and integrate in AOSP build
I want to build androidx's Appcompat(done some changes) and integrate in AOSP.
When I use the below command, it generates debug and release aar.
android_xsource_code/androidx/frameworks/support$ ./gradlew appcompat:appcompat:assemble
Output builds:
androidx/out/androidx/appcompat/appcompat/build/outputs/aar/appcompat-debug.aar
androidx/out/androidx/appcompat/appcompat/build/outputs/aar/appcompat-release.aar
Now which build I should integrate in AOSP?
Whether I can add the aar in prebuilts/maven_repo/android/androidx/appcompat/appcompat/appcompat-<debug/release>.aar?
How to map User Application(Android Studio build's apk using appcompatactivity) to this aar? because apk using activity refers the AOSP's framework/base/.../Activity.java.
How
